# Repeating an image vertically and horizontally in java

Tags: java, repeat

I need to try and duplicate and image, created by array(a), both vertically and horizontally to make a square full of the repeating image. So starting with 1 square image and I want to duplicate it 2 times horizontally and 2 times vertically it will create another image with 4 of the initial image, 2x2.

```
public static int[][] replicate(int[][] a) {
    int[][] replicated = new int[a.length * 2][a[0].length * 2];

    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                replicated[i][j + r * a[i].length] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                replicated[i + r * a.length][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return replicated;
}
```

This gets them across the horizontal for 1 line, and vertical for 1 line but does not fully fill in. So if I ran this I would be missing the bottom right of the 4 images. I'm having trouble putting them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] replicate(int[][] image) {
    int[][] replicated = new int[a.length * 2][];

    for (int y=0; y<image.length; y++) {
        int[] column = image[y];

        replicated[y] = new int[column.length * 2];
        replicated[y + image.length] = new int[column.length * 2];

        System.arraycopy(column, 0, replicated[y], 0, column.length);
        System.arraycopy(column, 0, replicated[y], column.length, column.length);
        System.arraycopy(column, 0, replicated[y + image.length], 0, column.length);
        System.arraycopy(column, 0, replicated[y + image.length], column.length, column.length);
    }

    return replicated;
}
```

There might be some problems with this code since I wrote it not in front of a compiler, but I think it gets the point across.

Also, if this is for painting the image, you should consider using a `TexturePaint` instead.